# how to refresh a particular part of a php page?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a php page which displays the result of a particular solution submitted by the user. The page is displaying an image "running" while the solution is checked in the back end and when the solution checking is finished in the back end the result is stored in the database.Now as the result got stored in the database the same php page which was displaying an image "running" should display the image and result that it got from the database. So, it needs to refresh every time to fetch the result from the database.I have used an iframe for that part of the page and passed the solution id using SESSION to the page which iframe is using and that page is fetching the data from the database. but the problem is that due to refreshing when a different solution(with different solution id) is submitted in another tab of the browser then both the previous and the current tab in the browser shows the current page since the solution id is passed using the SESSION variable. I tried Ajax also but not getting desired result. I want that a particular tab on the browser display the result of the solution which was submitted on that tab only. How can i do this please someone help.I surfed the net but dint got any desired result.

Comment: use an iframe .then you can

Comment: Using AJAX would be fine. could you show some of your code that show how you are using AJAX?

Comment: Do you know the [enter] key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, your problem is, that

- you allow the same session in two different browser tabs (or windows), so the session ID is not unique between solutions
- you store the solution id in the session, so the session id must be unique between solutions

You can work around your problem by removin either of these two conditions - either do not allow session re-use (bad idea IMHO) or use the **solution id** rather than the **session id** in your AJAX call for the iFrame refresh, e.g. as a GET parameter

Comment: i have used something like this 
  $_SESSION['sol_id']=$sol_id; on the result page and session_start();
$sol_id=$_SESSION['sol_id']; on the page that i am using as a refresh.. since the SESSIOn is unique it is creating problem when that page is refreshing again and again.. also i dont know much of AJAX will u please explain me how to do? it would be a great help for me

Comment: OKay thanks a lot i got it.. i passed the solution id with the link and then got that in the refresh page using $_GET .. and now its all fine... thnks a lot :)

Comment: Good to hear! You might want to mark your question as answered.